# MYSQL storage increasing unexpectedly (RDS)

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0, storage

I am total newbie to database game.
& I am using mysql 8.0 RDS 20GB free tier.

I don't have much data on it.(**just 300 Mb**)

But I always get a mail that **you have exceeded 85% of storage limit.**(approx 17Gb)

Also Under *monitoring* tab in rds panel it shows:- **Free Storage Space (MB) = 19.330Gb** ***(Constantly without any drop)***

**I have turned off :** *general log, slow logs, binlog,*

Can someone please help me whats consuming these storage. Is this something to do with INNODB?

Comment: check the data directory, there are the different file, also inndo log file and see if they are getting to big. Then yyou can see which option you need to change, to limit the file size.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I am a newbie, Can you please tell me how to access RDS data directory.(i googled it,but didnt found).

Should I limit innodb_data_file_path with a "max" at the end?

And sir,the Free Storage Space (MB) in monitoring tab stay constanly at  19.330Gb, so if something is really consuming space the this value must come down right?

Comment: check the db parameters https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html  where your data directory is, there you see also the paramerters for the logs, but to disable bin log general log an you must have benn already there

Comment: innodb_log_file_size = 134217728

Comment: innodb_data_home_dir = /rdsdbdata/db/innodb , but sir how can i access this location? what commands should i use?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-logs/ describes manner planned to view various logs.